# GNU-getline: strange behaviour about EOF

Tags: c, linux, eof

## Test

In order to find the behaviour of `getline()` when confronted with EOF, I wrote the following test:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t max = 100;
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    size_t len = getline(&buf, &max, stdin);
    printf("length %zu: %s", len, buf);
}
```

And input1 is:

> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Result:

```
 length 4: abc  //notice that '\n' is also taken into consideration and printed
```

Input2:

> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Exactly same output:

```
 length 4: abc
```

**It seems that the `EOF` is left out out by `getline()`**

## Source code

So I find the [source code of `getline()`](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/pecomato/0.0.15/gnu-getline_8c.html) and following is a related snippet of it (and I leave out some comments and irrelevant codes for conciseness):

```
 while ((c = getc (stream)) != EOF)
{
  /* Push the result in the line.  */
  (*lineptr)[indx++] = c;

  /* Bail out.  */
  if (c == delim)             //delim here is '\n'
   break;
}

/* Make room for the null character.  */
if (indx >= *n)
{
  *lineptr = realloc (*lineptr, *n + line_size);
  if (*lineptr == NULL)
   return -1;
  *n += line_size;
}

/* Null terminate the buffer.  */
(*lineptr)[indx++] = 0;

 return (c == EOF && (indx - 1) == 0) ? -1 : indx - 1;
```

## Question

So my question is:

- why length here is 4 (as far as I can see it should be 5)(as [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) says, It won't be a EOF if it not at the beginning of a line)

A similar question:[EOF behavior when accompanied by other values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162167/eof-behavior-when-accompanied-by-other-values) but notice **getline() in that question is different from GNU-getline**

> I use GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: As a test, use your progam's binary as its own input: `./a.out <a.out` It will report a large number (when I tried : 1317) . Next: hexdump your program `hexdump a.out | less` and look for the first `04` character (in my case it was at position 0x18). Conclusion: **the EOD (0x04) character is not special**. Explanation: EOD is just handled differntly by the terminal driver.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10766343/905902 for a demonstration of how the terminal handles "special" characters (It is about ^C, not ^D, but the mechanism is similar)

Comment: `len` is 4 because (`a` + `b` + `c` + `\n` = `4`). There is no need to use `ctrl+d`. Simply `a b c [enter]`.

Comment: @wildplasser Sorry for being so late. Thanks. Could you explain how did you reach the conclusion in detail for I didn't get it.

Comment: Most of it is covered by @mafso. My key point is: **there is no EOF character**. There (sometimes) is an EOF *condition* , which *sometimes* is translated into an int with value EOF. mafso 's reaction covers the cases where this reaction is delayed (by the terminal / the terminal driver / the buffering between the raw input and your program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> causes your terminal to flush the input buffer if it isn’t already flushed. Otherwise, the end-of-file indicator for the input stream is set. A newline also flushes the buffer.

So you didn't close the stream, but only flushed the input buffer, which is why `getline` doesn't see an end-of-file indicator.

In neither of these cases, a literal [EOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character) *character* (ASCII 0x04, `^D`) is received by `getline` (in order to do so, you can type <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>).

Type

> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

or

> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

to actually set the end-of-file indicator.

From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11):

> **Special characters**
>
> - EOF
>
> Special character on input, which is recognized if the `ICANON` flag is set. When received, all the bytes waiting to be read are immediately passed to the process without waiting for a `<newline>`, and the EOF is discarded. Thus, if there are no bytes waiting (that is, the EOF occurred at the beginning of a line), a byte count of zero shall be returned from the `read()`, representing an end-of-file indication. If `ICANON` is set, the EOF character shall be discarded when processed.

FYI, the ICANON flag is specified [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html).

Comment: Any reference about 'Ctrl-D causes your terminal to flush the input buffer'? Besides, the wikipedia says 'the driver converts a Control-D character at the start of a line into an end-of-file indicator.' Is it wrong?

Comment: Seems to be accurate. If you run `cat`, type some text without hitting enter, then press ^D, `cat` will immediate echo what you've typed so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I found [this on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character), although without a reference. Your quote from Wikipedia isn't wrong (and doesn't contradict me), it's just incomplete. It doesn't say what happens if `^D` is pressed not at the beginning of a line.

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html): _If a utility using the escaped <newline> convention detects an end-of-file condition immediately after an escaped <newline>, the results are unspecified._ Not that helpful, but `^D` seems to be POSIX-specified. Couldn't find it, though. This questions comes up here regularly, and all duplicates I've found don't cite a source either (and most don't mention at all what happens when `^D` is pressed not at the beginning of a line). Would be nice if we found something where this comes from/where this is specified.

Comment: Yuo cannot `send an EOF`. Your terminal sends an EOD and the terminal-driver interprets that specially and closes the input stream.

Comment: As I said: it is similar, except normally ^C well generate a signal, while ^D will close the stream. In both cases, the control character is intercepted and will not be seen by the program.

Comment: @wildplasser: EOF doesn't necessarily close the stream (see POSIX quote in the post). OP knows that EOF on the beginning of a line closes the stream, the question is what happens when it doesn't (and I think OP knows that not an EOF character is sent to `getline`, but `getline` checks for the end-of-file condition). But I agree that my answer could be improved. I'll edit soon.

Comment: I think we agree. See my `./a.out <a.out` example in the comment to the question. BTW IMHO the wording in POSIX is confusing, it makes people believe that there actually is an EOF character. And indeed: the CANON mode can change the terminal's behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for being so late. Good answer. One more question: what is the difference of EOF, EOT, EOD?

Comment: @Tony: I don't know of EOD ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) doesn't list it as an ASCII character), maybe a typo or a different name for EOT. EOT is part of ASCII (0x04), EOF isn't an ASCII character, but a character in the sense POSIX uses the term (that's what Wildplasser called confusing). A POSIX terminal converts EOT to EOF (if not preceded by ^V).